# Magento 1.9 - Admin sales order index template phtml file?

Tags: adminhtml

I am using Magento 1.9 and i've searched like the whole directory `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template` and I can not find the .phtml file answering for this page: `www.yourmagentostore.com/index.php/admin/sales_order/index/key/944964552ee91bc0eeeb09f63a57c97e/`

Can you please tell me where i can find the .phtml file which is answering for the Sales Order index page so i can edit the template.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that there is no .phtml file for sales_order/index controller.

Also You can check app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php
For Title of this page.

But page is running through this sales.xml

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="adminhtml/sales_order" name="sales_order.grid.container"></block>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_index>
```

So file where Sales Order is Manage that is Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order.php

Also you can check grid of this page. Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
Where you find Grid of Order Page.